# database query insert not working properly

Tags: java, mysql

The value of status is coming false instead of true. I have used the same insert query separately in database and it is working but in this it is not.The table in which I want to insert value contains 4 columns `departmentid`, `departmentname`, `company`, `place` and `departmentid` is auto increment. Could someone please correct it.

```
package bean;
import java.sql.*;


public  class LoginDao {
public static boolean validate(LoginBean bean){
    boolean status=false;
    try{
        Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        String sql="insert into department(departmentname,company,place)   values (?,?,?)";            
        PreparedStatement pstmt =con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(2,bean.getdepartment()); 
        pstmt.setString(3,bean.getcompany());
        pstmt.setString(4, bean.getplace());

        int rs=pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if(rs>0){status=true;}
    }catch(Exception e){}

    return status;
 }
}
```

In

```
pstmt.setString(2,bean.getdeparment());               
pstmt.setString(3,bean.getcompany());
pstmt.setString(4, bean.getplace());
```

I changed index value to 1,2,3 respectively but it still doesn't work.

This file is loginbean from which getdepartment(),getcompany,getplace method comes from.
    package bean;

```
public class LoginBean {
private String company,department,place;

public String getcompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setcompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getdepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setdepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public String getplace() {
    return place;
}

public void setplace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}  

}
```

Comment: does the `executeUpdate();` return -`1` ?

Comment: 1/ indexes are 1-based not 2-based. 2/ can you define not working

Comment: Also, your insert column order is (departmentname,company,place), but you are doing getcompany() first and getdepartment() second. Shouldn't those be flipped?

Comment: i have editedthe code i accidentally changed the ordered but it still not workingand also could you tell me what index value should  be 1,2,3 or 2,3,4

Comment: It is working now the problem was in get and set methods of login bean and index should be 1,2,3 thanks for pointing out the order mistake though.

Answer (score 3):

Hello Try this code and make sure that you are inserting values with same DataTypes as your Department table column have and hope it will work.

```
String sql="insert into department values(?,?,?)";            
    PreparedStatement pstmt =con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1,bean.getdepartment()); 
    pstmt.setString(2,bean.getcompany());
    pstmt.setString(3, bean.getplace());
```

Comment: Ummm,,,check your Database on a same table and run same query there with the dummy records......if it works fine so you have some syntax or connection or some minor error in your code.